# How to implement ProxyInterface hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy-classes

[Chapter 5, Basic O/R Mapping of hibernate DOCs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html)  says:
at section 5.1.3. Class

> You can declare a persistent class using the class element. For
>   example:

```
<class
    ...
    proxy="ProxyInterface"                        (7)
    ...
/>
```

with the short comment:

> proxy (optional): specifies an interface to use for lazy initializing
>   proxies. You can specify the name of the class itself.

Is there any example, specification, or a little more explanation of this interface usage?

Comment: "The proxy attribute enables lazy initialization of persistent instances of the class. 
Hibernate will initially return CGLIB proxies which implement the named interface. 
The actual persistent object will be loaded when a method of the proxy is invoked." What do look forward in an example ?

Comment: My english is not very well. What did you mean with your last question?

Comment: The text in my comments helps you understand the use of proxy attribute?

Comment: I have already read this comment, but I can't understand usages of this "ProxyInterface", can I implement it by myself? And where is the specification of this interface?